# Angular 7.1.4 no heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

Bom, estou tentando subir uma aplicação angular ( basicamente o get started que tem na documentação ) para o heroku, por o angular rodar em cima do node, eu sei que preciso definir a porta como `process.env.PORT || 3000` mas em nenhum lugar essa porta esta definida, localmente eu consegui mudar a porta passando ela na linha de comando para o `ng` mas isso não funciona no mt bem no heroku.

O projeto é esse : https://github.com/MatheusRBarbosa/stopot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um `server.js` basico e criei um script para o heroku instanciar esse server